# Adding "AllowOverride None" to my .htaccess gives 500 error

Tags: apache-2.4

I want to place a .htaccess file in the root of my public_html directory, but I want that the only .htacess file that apache2 looks for.

When I place `AllowOverride None` in that .htaccess file, I get a 500 internal server error.  Take it out, and it works fine.

How can I prevent the server for searching for other .htaccess files or overriding my current .htaccess file?

Comment: You will have far less problems, better security and performances if you just stop altogether using `htaccess` files in this case and just add what you need in generic configuration files.

Answer (score 2):

The [`AllowOverride`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#allowoverride) directive is not valid in `.htaccess` files.
The only context that directive can be used in is inside a `<Directory>` block in your main httpd.conf or in the equivalent configuration snippets loaded into the main httpd.conf by `Include` and `IncludeOptional` directives.

If you have access to the main httpd.conf it is better to simply place the directives you want to use in your .htaccess directly there instead. https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/htaccess.html#when